# How to solve $y'=\frac {e^{x-y}}{y-1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please give me some hint how to solve this problem.

> Suppose that $y(x)$ solves the differential equation $y'=\dfrac {e^{x-y}}{y-1}$ and that $y(x)\to 0$ when $x\to -\infty$.
>   Compute $y\left(\ln\left(2-\frac 3e\right)\right)$.

I tried to solve the DE:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac {e^x} {e^y\left(y-1\right)}$

$e^y\left(y-1\right)dy=e^xd$

$\int^y\left(t-1\right)e^tdt-\int^x e^udu=C$

$\left(y-2\right)e^y-e^x=C$

$lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(y-2\right)e^y-\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x=C \Rightarrow C=0$.

Thus we have $\left(y-2\right)e^y=e^x$, 
but this is not helping to evaluate $y\left(ln\left(2-\frac 3e\right)\right)$:
$2-\frac3e=\left(y-2\right)e^y$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Validate? Maybe evaluate?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post according to your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One knows that $(y(x)-2)\mathrm e^{y(x)}=\mathrm e^x+C$ for every $x$, for some $C$. If $y(x)\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$, then $(y(x)-2)\mathrm e^{y(x)}\to-2$ when $\mathrm e^x\to0$ hence $C=-2$ and $(y(x)-2)\mathrm e^{y(x)}=\mathrm e^x-2$ for every $x$. If $x_0=\ln(2-3/\mathrm e)$, this yields $G(y(x_0))=-3/\mathrm e$, where $G$ is the function $$G(t)=(t-2)\mathrm e^t. 
$$
Unexpectedly (to me), some more work is needed to deduce $y(x_0)$ from this.
Here is a graph of the function $G$:

[image]

Thus, the equation $G(t)=-3/\mathrm e$ has two solutions, one negative $t=-1$ and the other positive $t=2+W(-3/\mathrm e^3)\approx1.82$. Note that $y(-\infty)=0$ and that $y'(x)=(y(x)-1)\mathrm e^{y(x)-x}$, hence $y'(x)\lt0$ for every $x$, in particular the function $x\mapsto y(x)$ is decreasing and $y(x_0)\lt0$. Thus, $y(x_0)$ is the negative solution of the equation $G(t)=-3/\mathrm e$, that is, $$y(x_0)=-1.$$

Comment: $(y(x_0)-2)\mathrm e^{y(x_0)}=-3/\mathrm e=(-1-2)\mathrm e^{-1} \iff y=-1$

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. There is a second solution $y=W\left(-\frac{3}{e^3}\right)+2$

Comment: @Did. NO ! I forgot the $-2$ ! Thanks for pointing my stupidity. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You might not be the most stupid person in the room... :-) A (not very difficult) supplementary argument is needed to determine whether $y(x_0)$ is equal to $-1$ or to "your" solution.

Comment: ((And yet another example of "accepting" an answer much too hastily.))